# Why does the literal string """"""" (seven quotes) give an error?

Tags: python, string, literals

Processing client's input we often use the `strip()` method.  If we want to remove starting-ending symbols from some specific set we just place all it in the parameter.

The code:

```
".yes' ".strip(". '")
```

obviously gives `'yes'` string as a result.
When I try to remove set `' ".` The result depends from this symbols order. Variant   `".yes' ".strip(""" ."'""")` works properly, when variant with symbol `"` at the end gives the `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)`.

Why literal string `"""""""` (using seven quotes) gives error? It is just the same `'"'!"`.

Let's look documentation:

[Triple quoted: '''Three single quotes''', """Three double quotes"""](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq)

and

[image: Language reference]

Click [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) to verify.  So

1. `longstring` i.e.  `"""longstringitem"""`
2. `longstringitem`  may be a single char.

So do we have to rewrite documentation or interpreter?

I've register my question on Python documentation issue. Can see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/103594).

Comment: "But no place in documentation that says: `"""""""` (7) is wrong." Correct. `""""""` (6) is ok, and the following `"` is wrong. Re: Update 5: Yes, this is expected. The start of the string literal is triple-quoted. The quote following is allowed because it is not a triple-quote. Thus, the  `"TEXT"""` terminates the string literal, and you once again have an extra `"` at the end.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance may be. thanks. But why I have -6 for the same question that another boy has +3    ?  It is the question for me now....

Comment: I can't say for sure as I have no active votes on either question. However, just some points of advice: I think that the tone you have used in your interactions with other users has been seen as too demanding and critical. Try to see things from others' points of view. If your perspectives don't line up, ask questions to arrive at the truth. Answer criticisms objectively and critique objectively. Not to say that there can't be any subjectivity in your questions, but it should never be the focal point.

Comment: And also, I don't blame you for this as English is not your first language, but please avoid calling other users here "boy." In English, that implies that the other user is an immature child. I would just use "user" or "person" instead.

Answer (score 6):

This reflects the documented behaviour as per the Python language spec around [lexical analysis of strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings):

> In triple-quoted literals, unescaped newlines and quotes are allowed (and are retained), except that three unescaped quotes in a row terminate the literal. (A “quote” is the character used to open the literal, i.e. either ' or ".)

The crucial point here is that "three unescaped quotes in a row terminate the literal".  So if you begin a literal with `"""`, that literal ends as soon as another `"""` sequence is encountered: the parser doesn't look ahead of that to try to infer a different endpoint for the literal.

When the parser encounters `"""""""` (a run of seven double-quotes), therefore:

1. The 1st, 2nd and 3rd characters tell the parser it's dealing with a literal delimited by triple double-quotes.
2. The 4th, 5th and 6th characters constitute those "three unescaped quotes" so they terminate the literal.
3. The 7th character is then `"` with no following `"` that it can be paired with, so that 7th character constitutes an unterminated literal. The parser fails with `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal`.

It's worth mentioning that backslash-escaping can still be used to prevent the quote character being treated as a quote. For example:

```
s = """\""""
print(s)
```

prints:

```
"
```

Comment: As I have said. if we carefully read the formal definithion of `longstring` from documentation You can easy see that 7 in a row " is valid literal. Formal algebra logic in Python documentation and Python interpretator and text you was applyed are in antagonism. Not my fault )))) Again """"""" is valid variant from Bacus-Nour form from Python language description

Comment: The grammar in the doc is only partly 'formal'.  The last 3 productions quoted in the question are partly informal.  The doc grammar is not and can not be the grammar used to define the parser.  It is a human readable version that *must be read* along with the explanation that follows.  The explanation starts with "One syntactic restriction not indicated by these productions...".  Another is the the paragraph 'slothrop' quoted, which defines 7 quotes as invalid.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy  so how anybody can say that parser works properly or unproperly if I can not see formal gramma?

7 "  in row is a misstake because parser say 'It is mistake'? Really?
Nice testing practice

Comment: The doc, as I read it, and the implementation both say the `"""""""` is an error.  So there is no implementation bug.  That is all I care about here.  You can check the regression tests to see if this is one of the many error examples tested.  I have no more interest in this.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy  Hi ! so what behavior will produce 8 " do you think? """""""" - try it in your python

Comment: @VasylKolomiets as per matszwecja's comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76044166/why-is-alowed-at-the-start-triple-quated-string-but-prohibited-at-the-end/76044224#comment136223561_76044224

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is determined with one interesting thing in Python parser. You can read it [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tokenize.py).

At line near 114  you see:

```
# Tail end of """ string.
Double3 = r'[^"\\]*(?:(?:\\.|"(?!""))[^"\\]*)*"""'
```

This part of the code defines regular expression for the tail of triple quoted literal.  We can see that separate `"` is allowed BUT if it does not followed with another `"`.  So logically it allowed but this regular expression prohibit it.